# NSString Question

Tags: iphone, cocoa, nsstring

I'm trying to extract the names from this list:

```
new String:  blood cz            TheDeAtH              TBH DragonFire   Scotsman          King Kot            BobLeeSwagger          AffeMitWaffe    Jackobo          D L  fatality         Jack bobo           telex             apa           Tiger            zip     Guronzan          noobmaster           fear           piotrekjankiewi         RoCJackal
```

These names will then have to be written into an array. I've done this so far:

```
NSString *newString = [[test componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:
       [[NSCharacterSet letterCharacterSet] invertedSet]] 
         componentsJoinedByString:@";"]; //yes there are spaces in the above list, previously they were replaced by ;
```

I then load it into an array:

```
 NSArray *chunks = [newString componentsSeparatedByString:@";"];
```

This works, but for the name "blood cz" for example, it takes blood and cz as a seperate thing in the array, but i need them to be together.

Does anyone have an idea of how I could achieve this? I've been breaking my head over this, because Im not able to seperate the strings. When taking the whitespaces out, its all together and I can seperate the strings, reason being that these strings are being taken from a gameserver website, where playernames change...

Comment: But how do you know they belong together? What are the other names there? Does "TBH" and "DragonFire" belong together as a "TBH Dragonfire". Is it the double space that makes the difference?

Comment: i knw they belong together because theyre fetched from a website, so i just checked the website.

Comment: I just now saw your answer after I posted my answer. Fetching it from a website means you might have some HTML tags you could interpret or something like this. The are maybe originally separated by some <LI> tag. Check it out.

Comment: well it seems to be a table - (online players) http://www.gametracker.com/server/82.1.127.18:28960/ - at this point i have stripped the tags, but might check the separators out using nsscanner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This worked

```
NSString         *mystring = @"blood cz            TheDeAtH              TBH DragonFire   Scotsman          King Kot            BobLeeSwagger          AffeMitWaffe    Jackobo          D L  fatality         Jack bobo           telex             apa           Tiger            zip     Guronzan          noobmaster           fear           piotrekjankiewi         RoCJackal";
NSString *mystring2 = [mystring stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"  "  withString:@";"];
    NSCharacterSet   *separator   = [NSCharacterSet     characterSetWithCharactersInString:@";"];
NSArray          *chunks      = [mystring2 componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:separator];

    for(NSString * myStr in chunks) {
        NSLog(myStr);
    }
```

You still have to left trim the names (cutting of leading spaces) but I left some work for you.

Also I want to add that this is best called a "hack". Because it will NOT WORK anymore if a user enters a double space in a name.

So I would take a step back and ask myself why I get such a lousy string to interpret and try to solve the problem at the source of the problem ... This is my core answer: Check out whether you could get a better string.

Answer (score 1):

You can't just replace the whitespaces with ; only if there are two whitespaces?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but this one looks for me like a tab \t rather than a space. Another solution is like Jonas's one. You can try to separate 2 strings only when there are more than 2 spaces between them